# Android Talkback issue in latest devices

Tags: javascript, android, talkback

I develop a web application in the Javascript and I using Talkback for visually impaired.
But the issue is why touchstart event is not rasied in Talkback environment. Is this normal operation?
In Apple's IOS touchstart event raises first and click event comes.

How do I raise touchstart event in Talkback mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: clickBtn.current.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {}); =>> IOS working, Android NOT... I want to know why

Comment: Here is my source code. https://github.com/nooni85/event-tester